# Solving Bidding Logic - Python/If and While Loops

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, while-loop

I am trying to simulate a bidding logic on the following rules and am stuck with an error:

- I have two dataframes of equal length (demand, supply), each row in the respecitive df is a supply bid demand request (in integers)
- They are sorted based on their respective bidding ranks, i.e. lower ranks get to trade first
- Starting from the top of both tables, a trade of 1 unit happens, while demand_price > supply_price
- If demand is fullfilled, continue to next demand request
- If supply is == 0 or demand_price < supply_price, go to the next supply offer (s_row+=1)

```
demand=pd.DataFrame({'demand_amount':[29,27,26,27,22,27,27,30,26,22,23],
                     'demand_price':[18.211687,20.810708,20.510476,19.797774,18.935372,19.881470,18.747783,18.566829,18.658478,18.600443,20.308458],
                     'rank_buy':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11], 
                     'fulfilled_demand':[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                     'total_price_paying':[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], 
                     'remaining_demand':[29,27,26,27,22,27,27,30,26,22,23]})
```

```
supply=pd.DataFrame({'supply_amount':[23,30,24,24,27,27,25,24,22,33,25],
                     'supply_price':[18.933508,18.204136,18.029734,19.918134,17.480024,19.318488,19.432806,19.853056,18.672518,18.672518,18.672518],
                     'rank_sell':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11], 
                     'fulfilled_supply':[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                     'total_price_receiving':[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], 
                     'remaining_supply':[23,30,24,24,27,27,25,24,22,33,25]})
```

```
for d_row in range(0,len(demand)-1):
    while demand['remaining_demand'].iloc[d_row]>0:
        s_row=0
        while demand['remaining_demand'].iloc[d_row]>0:
            if (demand['demand_price'].iloc[d_row]>supply['supply_price'].iloc[s_row]) and (supply['remaining_supply'].iloc[s_row]>0):
                while (demand['demand_price'].iloc[d_row]>supply['supply_price'].iloc[s_row]) and (supply['remaining_supply'].iloc[s_row]>0) and (demand['remaining_demand'].iloc[d_row]>0):
                    demand['fulfilled_demand'].iloc[d_row] += 1
                    demand['remaining_demand'].iloc[d_row]-=1
                    supply['remaining_supply'].iloc[s_row]-= 1
                    demand['total_price_paying'].iloc[d_row]+=supply['supply_price'].iloc[s_row]
                    supply['total_price_receiving'].iloc[s_row]+=supply['supply_price'].iloc[s_row]
                    remaining_demand=demand['remaining_demand'].iloc[d_row]
                    remaining_supply=supply['remaining_supply'].iloc[s_row]
                    print(s_row, "transferred 1 to", d_row, ", remaining_demand=",remaining_demand,"in row", d_row,". remaining_supply:", remaining_supply)
            elif (demand['demand_price'].iloc[d_row]<supply['supply_price'].iloc[s_row]) or (supply['remaining_supply'].iloc[s_row]==0):
                while supply['remaining_supply'].iloc[s_row]==0:
                    s_row+=1
                while (demand['demand_price'].iloc[d_row]<supply['supply_price'].iloc[s_row]):
                    s_row+=1
```

The error "single positional indexer is out-of-bounds" happens after a certain amount of trades (for specific point see the "print" output for detailled insights). My observation as of now: it does not identify another unit where demand_price > supply_price, keeps adding s_row +=1 and therefore ends up out-of-bounds. As a consequence, it doesn't consider the remaining supply lines anymore, e.g. remaining 19 units at index 3 which could be met at demand index 10, where the condition supply_price < demand_price is met. I guess I need a line that resets the s_row count in this case and checks the whole dataframe from top to bottom again, but I really don't manage to get there..

Very thankful for any idea how to solve this!!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the Stackoverfow

As you correctly identified `s_row` gets out of bound so I'll look into where `s_row` and `d_row` variables are incremented to see why it goes out of bounds

`d_row` seems to be incremented by for-loop `for d_row in range(0,len(demand)-1):` and if `len(demand)-1` part is correct it shouldn't go out of bounds and terminate at the end so that's good. Now let's go to `s_row`

`s_row` could be incremented in two while-loops:

```
while supply['remaining_supply'].iloc[s_row]==0:
    s_row+=1
while (demand['demand_price'].iloc[d_row]<supply['supply_price'].iloc[s_row]):
    s_row+=1
```

The problem is that those while-loops are not correctly terminated and will go out of bounds if last item is not equal 0 `supply['remaining_supply'].iloc[s_row]==0` similarly other loop too. To terminate while-loop before it goes out of bounds could be done by:

```
while supply['remaining_supply'].iloc[s_row]==0:
    if s_row >= len(supply) - 1:  # Here's the check which stops it going out of bounds
            # s_row = 0 # You might want to reset variables or something here too
        break # Terminate this while loop
    s_row+=1

while (demand['demand_price'].iloc[d_row]<supply['supply_price'].iloc[s_row]):
    if s_row >= len(supply) - 1:  # Same here
        break
    s_row+=1
```

Or

```
while s_row < len(supply) - 1 and supply['remaining_supply'].iloc[s_row]==0:
    s_row+=1
    
while s_row < len(supply) - 1 and demand['demand_price'].iloc[d_row]<supply['supply_price'].iloc[s_row]:       
    s_row+=1
```

But after fixing this code gets stuck in an infinite while-loop (or even loops) because there is still demand but no supply for affordable price

```
while demand['remaining_demand'].iloc[d_row]>0:
```

That requires another stop condition. To break out of nested loops you need some kind of variable e.g. `is_supply_affordable`. So my final code looks like this (can't guarantee correctness or that it won't break in some edge cases but at least here's some ideas)

```
for d_row in range(0,len(demand)-1):
    is_supply_affordable = True  # Flag to track if there is affordable supply  # <--------- ADDED FLAG HERE ---------
    while is_supply_affordable and demand['remaining_demand'].iloc[d_row]>0:  # <--------- ADDED FLAG HERE ---------
        s_row=0
        while is_supply_affordable and demand['remaining_demand'].iloc[d_row]>0:  # <--------- ADDED FLAG HERE ---------
            if (demand['demand_price'].iloc[d_row]>supply['supply_price'].iloc[s_row]) and (supply['remaining_supply'].iloc[s_row]>0):
                while (demand['demand_price'].iloc[d_row]>supply['supply_price'].iloc[s_row]) and (supply['remaining_supply'].iloc[s_row]>0) and (demand['remaining_demand'].iloc[d_row]>0):
                    demand['fulfilled_demand'].iloc[d_row] += 1
                    demand['remaining_demand'].iloc[d_row]-=1
                    supply['remaining_supply'].iloc[s_row]-= 1
                    demand['total_price_paying'].iloc[d_row]+=supply['supply_price'].iloc[s_row]
                    supply['total_price_receiving'].iloc[s_row]+=supply['supply_price'].iloc[s_row]
                    remaining_demand=demand['remaining_demand'].iloc[d_row]
                    remaining_supply=supply['remaining_supply'].iloc[s_row]
                    print(s_row, "transferred 1 to", d_row, ", remaining_demand=",remaining_demand,"in row", d_row,". remaining_supply:", remaining_supply)
            elif (demand['demand_price'].iloc[d_row]<supply['supply_price'].iloc[s_row]) or (supply['remaining_supply'].iloc[s_row]==0):

                # --------- CHANGED STUFF BELOW ---------

                while s_row < len(supply) - 1 and supply['remaining_supply'].iloc[s_row]==0:
                    s_row+=1
                while s_row < len(supply) - 1 and demand['demand_price'].iloc[d_row]<supply['supply_price'].iloc[s_row]:       
                    s_row+=1

                if s_row >= len(supply) - 1: 
                    # --------- IF THIS REACHES END IT MEANS THERE'S NO MORE AFFORDABLE SUPPLY ---------
                    is_supply_affordable = False
                    break
                    # Next code execution goes above and skips all while-loops and goes to the for-loops to get next d_row
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Many Thanks @Combinacijus for tackling my problem and taking the time!! What you're saying sounds absolutely logical and I think the additional variable is_supply_affordable might have been what I missed. The code doesn't give an error message anymore but it also doesn't reiterate over the leftover (affordable) demands, might have to build in an s_row-= somewhere..  But you got me on a good track, will look into it later and keep you posted!!

Comment: @LinaAntelmann Happy to help! s_row-= would be messy and hard to terminate. Better to start from s_row=0 or maybe s_row=1 or add `for s_row in range(0,len(supply)-1)` so it iterates multiple times and terminates itself. I'm not sure loops are getting nested real fast